# using select to read from socket and stdin

Tags: c, sockets, select, stdin, ncurses

I'm writing a ncurses based chat program. At first, I wrote just networking stuff (without ncurses) and everything worked fine, but after adding graphics I can't get the client app to work properly.

The main problem is reading from stdin and socket at the same time. In ncurses-less version I've used pthread and it worked like charm. Alas, it seems that pthread and ncurses don't go together very well, so I had to find another solution.
I thought that select() would do, but it still only reads from stdin and completely ignores the socket.

Here is the whole code: [code](http://paste.org/pastebin/view/32486/)

The interesting part is:

```
char message[1024];
fd_set master;
fd_set read_fds;

FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

FD_SET(0,&master);
FD_SET(s,&master); // s is a socket descriptor
while(true){
read_fds = master;
if (select(2,&read_fds,NULL,NULL,NULL) == -1){
  perror("select:");
  exit(1);
}
// if there are any data ready to read from the socket
if (FD_ISSET(s, &read_fds)){
  n = read(s,buf,max);
  buf[n]=0;
  if(n<0)
  {
    printf("Blad odczytu z gniazdka");
    exit(1);
  } 
  mvwprintw(output_window,1,1,"%s\n",buf);
}
// if there is something in stdin
if (FD_ISSET(0, &read_fds)){
  getstr(message);
  move(CURS_Y++,CURS_X);
  if (CURS_Y == LINES-2){
    CURS_Y = 1;
  }
  n = write(s,message,strlen(message));
  if (n < 0){
    perror("writeThread:");
    exit(1);
  }
}
}
```

It's possible that I don't fully understand how select() works, or maybe I shouldn't have connect()ed the socket.. I'm lost here. I would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: you know that the first thing you do is exit the program when something comes in vai the socket?

Comment: also do not use FD_ZERO( 0, use FD_SET( fileno( stdin ), ...

Comment: sorry, exit was there only to see if the program will ever get to that point. thanks for pointing that out though :P

Comment: I think you're mistaken to think ncurses and threads are incompatible. If you're having trouble you're doing something wrong (like trying to manipulate curses data structures from multiple threads simultaneously).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in the `select()`.
The first parameter is **not** the number of file descriptors you are passing in *read_fds*, but it's the highest socket ID + 1.

From the man page:

> The first nfds descriptors are checked in each set; i.e., the
>   descriptors from 0 through nfds-1 in the descriptor sets are examined.  (Example: If you have set two file descriptors "4" and "17", nfds should  not be "2", but rather "17 + 1" or "18".)

So in your code, instead of '2', try passing 's+1'.

Comment: thanks, not it get through FD_ISSET(s,&read_fds), but still doesn't print the buffer on the screen. I guess now it's just a ncurses problem, I'll try to tackle it tomorrow. Thank you :)
Ps. if you have any idea why isn't it printing let me know!

Comment: i forgot about wrefresh after printing. problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the highest file descriptor to select:

```
if (select(s + 1,&read_fds,NULL,NULL,NULL) == -1){
```

select() needs to know the number of file descriptors that it is supposed to watch.

Comment: it is suppose to watch only 2 descriptors - stdin and s

Comment: No, the number isn't the number of file descriptors, it's the one greater than the highest file descriptor. and "s + 1" is certainly bigger than 2.