# Send and receive message on both ends

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I have the following client and server code.

server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/utsname.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define MAX_DATA 1024
#define BUFFER 1024

int _GetHostName(char *buffer, int lenght);

const char MESSAGE[]="Hello, World!\n";
const int BACK_LOG=5;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int serverSocket=0, on=0, port=0, status=0, childPid=0;
    struct hostent *hostPtr=NULL;
    char hostname[80]="";
    char data[MAX_DATA];
    struct sockaddr_in serverName={0};

    char input[BUFFER];
    char output[BUFFER];
    int len;


    if(2!= argc){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    port=atoi(argv[1]);
    serverSocket=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(-1==serverSocket){
        perror("socket()");
        exit(1);
    }

    on=1;
    status=setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *)&on, sizeof(on));
    if(-1==status){
        perror("setsockopt(...,SO_REUSEADDRE,...)");
    }

    {
        struct linger linger={0};
        linger.l_onoff=1;
        linger.l_linger=30;
        status=setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (const char*)&linger, sizeof(linger));
        if(-1==status){
            perror("setsockopt(...,SO_LINGER,...)");
        }
    }

    status=_GetHostName(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
    if(-1==status){
        perror("_GetHostName()");
        exit(1);
    }

    hostPtr=gethostbyname(hostname);
    if(NULL==hostPtr){
        perror("gethostbyname()");
        exit(1);
    }

    (void)memset(&serverName,0,sizeof(serverName));
    (void)memcpy(&serverName.sin_addr, hostPtr->h_addr,hostPtr->h_length);

    serverName.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverName.sin_port=htons(port);

    status=bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverName,sizeof(serverName));
    if(-1==status){
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }


    status=listen(serverSocket, BACK_LOG);
    if(-1==status){
        perror("listen()");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;){
        struct sockaddr_in clientName={0};
        int slaveSocket, clientLength=sizeof(clientName);

        (void)memset(&clientName,0,sizeof(clientName));

        slaveSocket=accept(serverSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&clientName, & clientLength);
        if(-1==slaveSocket){
            perror("accept()");
            exit(1);
        }

        childPid=fork();

        switch(childPid){
            case -1:perror("fork()");
            exit(1);
            case 0: close(serverSocket);
            if(-1==getpeername(slaveSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientName, &clientLength)){
                perror("getpeername()");
            }else{
                printf("Connection request from %s \n", inet_ntoa(clientName.sin_addr));

                int data_len=1;

                while(data_len){
                    data_len=recv(slaveSocket,data, MAX_DATA,0);
                    if(data_len){
                        //send(slaveSocket,data,data_len,0);

                        data[data_len]='\0';
                        printf("CLIENT: %s", data);

                        printf("SERVER : ");
                        fgets(input,BUFFER, stdin);
                        send(slaveSocket, input, strlen(input),0);
                    }


                }

            }

            printf("Client disconnected\n");
            close(slaveSocket);
            exit(0);
            default:close(slaveSocket);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int _GetHostName(char *buffer,int length){
    struct utsname sysname={0};
    int status=0;

    status=uname(&sysname);
    if(-1!=status){
        strncpy(buffer,sysname.nodename,length);
    }
    return(status);
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>


#define BUFFER 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int clientSocket, remotePort, status=0;
    struct hostent *hostPtr=NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in serverName={0};
    char buffer[256]="";
    char *remoteHost=NULL;

    char input[BUFFER];
    char output[BUFFER];
    int len;


    if(3!=argc){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <serverHost> <serverPort> \n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    remoteHost=argv[1];
    remotePort=atoi(argv[2]);
    clientSocket=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(-1==clientSocket){
        perror("socket()");
        exit(1);
    }

    hostPtr=gethostbyname(remoteHost);
    if(NULL==hostPtr){
        hostPtr=gethostbyaddr(remoteHost,strlen(remoteHost), AF_INET);
        if(NULL==hostPtr){
            perror("Error resolving server address ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    serverName.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverName.sin_port=htons(remotePort);
    (void)memcpy(&serverName.sin_addr,hostPtr->h_addr,hostPtr->h_length);

    status=connect(clientSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverName,sizeof(serverName));
    if(-1==status){
        perror("connect()");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1){
        printf("CLIENT: ");
        fgets(input,BUFFER, stdin);
        send(clientSocket, input, strlen(input),0);

        len=recv(clientSocket, output,BUFFER, 0);
        output[len]='\0';
        printf("SERVER : %s\n",output);
    }
    close(clientSocket);


}
```

The server code above can receive and send message from and to the client. The client also can receive and send message from and to the server. However, they can only send one message at a time. Before the client can send more message, it needs to wait for the server first to send single message. The same with the server. 
**How to make them receive and send multiple messages without waiting for the other end to reply?**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "multiple messages". You could easily make the server handle multiple clients, which I think your code is already doing. Try running multiple instances of the client and see if that's what you want.

Comment: What I mean is that if the client send message for the first time, it will be sent successfully. But if it send again, it cannot send because it has to wait first for the server to respond. If the server sends a message, then that's that time the client can successfully send again. The main question is how to make a while loop that wait for incoming message and at the same time accepts input to be sent to the other.

Comment: in the screenshot included, in the client side, it says `CLIENT: ` meaning its his time to send while the server is waiting for message from client and cannot send yet. after the client sends, the server will display the message send by client and that's the time that he can send message and the client will wait for incoming message.

Comment: I've attempted to write an answer. Please see if that's what you want.

Comment: Setting the SO_LINGER option on a listening socket is a completely meaningless operation, and should be avoided even on active sockets.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that, you want to continue sending without waiting for the server's response.

A simple way to implement that is to use the `poll()` function to check first for any response. You will only call `recv()` when you're sure there is data to be read.

```
int pollForData(int sock) {
    struct pollfd pollSock;
    pollSock.fd = sock;
    pollSock.events = POLLIN;
    return  poll(&pollSock, 1, 10);
}
```

Comment: why does it says `storage size of ‘pollSock’ isn’t known`?

Comment: You need to include the appropriate headers. `poll.h` contains the definitions for `pollfd`.

Comment: I tried it like this `int data_len;
                while(1){
                    if(pollForData(slaveSocket)){
                        data_len=recv(slaveSocket,data, MAX_DATA,0);
                        data[data_len]='\0';
                        printf("CLIENT: %s", data);
                    }else{
                        printf("SERVER : ");
                        fgets(input,BUFFER, stdin);
                        send(slaveSocket, input, strlen(input),0);
                    }

                }` it allows to send many massages but will not display immediately.

Comment: Yes, that's happening because `fgets()` is also a blocking function. The while loop pauses because `fgets()` is waiting for input. One way to solve is by calliing the `poll()` function on `stdin` too.

Comment: calling the `poll()` function to `stdin`. How to do that? Do I have to make another function similar to `pollForData()` with string parameter? how to use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124148/discussion-between-harish-nagisetty-and-quickbrownfox).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) on the socket and on `stdin` and perform a read/receive from whichever of the both becomes ready to read. If reading is done write/send either to `stdout` or to the socket.

In the server "socket" would refer to the *accepted* socket, in the client to the *connected* socket.

---

Unrelated, but still important:

This

```
char data[MAX_DATA];

...

data_len=recv(slaveSocket,data, MAX_DATA,0);
if(data_len){
  data[data_len]='\0';

...
```

could lead to buffer overflow the moment `MAX_DATA` bytes had been received, as then the `0` would be written 1  off the end of `data`.

To fix this define `data` like this:

```
char data[MAX_DATA + 1];
```

---

Also *all* code *completely* misses error checking for the calls to `recv()` and `send()`. This is bad.

Comment: Thank you for the note on error checking.  I'm sorry but I really don't know how to use the `select`. Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @quickbrownfox: https://www.google.com/search?q=example+on+how+to+use+select+to+monitor+stdin+and+socket brings up http://stackoverflow.com/q/5825748/694576 and tons of others. See how far you get and then come back here with another specific question, please.